# Iterator Performance

Tags: c++, iterator

Does implementing and using an iterator introduce any kind of performance penalty, in comparison to directly using a pointer?

(suppose we use the highest compiler optimization...)

The code is from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/

```
// std::iterator example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::iterator, std::input_iterator_tag

class MyIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, int>
{
  int* p;
public:
  MyIterator(int* x) :p(x) {}
  MyIterator(const MyIterator& mit) : p(mit.p) {}
  MyIterator& operator++() {++p;return *this;}
  MyIterator operator++(int) {MyIterator tmp(*this); operator++(); return tmp;}
  bool operator==(const MyIterator& rhs) {return p==rhs.p;}
  bool operator!=(const MyIterator& rhs) {return p!=rhs.p;}
  int& operator*() {return *p;}
};

int main () {
  int numbers[]={10,20,30,40,50};
  MyIterator from(numbers);
  MyIterator until(numbers+5);
  for (MyIterator it=from; it!=until; it++)
    std::cout << *it << ' ';
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

[gcc godbolt for iterator](https://godbolt.org/g/X0sCcB)

[gcc godbolt for raw pointer](https://godbolt.org/g/PQAJ51)

Comment: Just a comment; you may want to prefer [cppreference](http://cppreference.com/) over cplusplus.com as a reference site...

Comment: @JesperJuhl such religious, ungrounded and bald suggestions make one to want to use cplusplus.com as a reference site.

Comment: @Öö Tiib Whatever. Do as you please. But cplusplus.com tends to have inaccurate, plainly wrong and incomplete contents. cppreference.com tends to have more complete and more accurate contents. But use whatever you like..

Comment: @JesperJuhl There are mistakes in information of both sites but we should not cast stones from a glass house stackoverflow) . ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does implementing and using an iterator introduce any kind of
>   performance penalty, in comparison to directly using a pointer?\

This question is problematic, as it assumes **all** iterators are iterators to contiguous array in memory. but an iterator is a **generalization** to a pointer. it may also be an iterator to a linked list, a hash map, a red-black tree, etc. so with this case, you can't really compare the performance of a  contiguous-array-based iterator to an iterator of more complex types, like trees.

now, let me ask the question differently:

> Does implementing and using an iterator to a contiguous array introduce any kind of
>   performance penalty, in comparison to directly using a pointer?\

well, not really, the compiler pretty much strips most of C++ class wrappers and optimize the assembly code to the same assembly that was generated using a C-pointer.

don't believe me? here is the generated assembly code from **your code**, compiled with visual studio 2015 update 4, x64:

```
int main() {
00007FF7A1D71000  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx  
00007FF7A1D71005  push        rdi  
00007FF7A1D71006  sub         rsp,40h  
00007FF7A1D7100A  mov         rax,qword ptr [__security_cookie (07FF7A1D75000h)]  
00007FF7A1D71011  xor         rax,rsp  
00007FF7A1D71014  mov         qword ptr [rsp+38h],rax  
00007FF7A1D71019  movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr [__xmm@000000280000001e000000140000000a (07FF7A1D732C0h)]  
00007FF7A1D71021  lea         rbx,[numbers]  
00007FF7A1D71026  movdqu      xmmword ptr [numbers],xmm0  
00007FF7A1D7102C  mov         dword ptr [rsp+30h],32h  
00007FF7A1D71034  mov         edi,5  
00007FF7A1D71039  nop         dword ptr [rax]  
00007FF7A1D71040  mov         edx,dword ptr [rbx]  
00007FF7A1D71042  mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (07FF7A1D73080h)]  
00007FF7A1D71049  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (07FF7A1D73088h)]  
00007FF7A1D7104F  mov         rcx,rax  
00007FF7A1D71052  mov         dl,20h  
00007FF7A1D71054  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (07FF7A1D71110h)  
00007FF7A1D71059  lea         rbx,[rbx+4]  
00007FF7A1D7105D  sub         rdi,1  
00007FF7A1D71061  jne         main+40h (07FF7A1D71040h)  
00007FF7A1D71063  mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (07FF7A1D73080h)]  
00007FF7A1D7106A  mov         dl,0Ah  
00007FF7A1D7106C  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (07FF7A1D71110h)  
00007FF7A1D71071  xor         eax,eax  
}
```

here is the code using c pointers:

```
int main() {
    int numbers[] = { 10,20,30,40,50 };
    for (MyIterator it = numbers; it != numbers + 5; it++)
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}

int main() {
00007FF6A72E1000  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx  
00007FF6A72E1005  push        rdi  
00007FF6A72E1006  sub         rsp,40h  
00007FF6A72E100A  mov         rax,qword ptr [__security_cookie (07FF6A72E5000h)]  
00007FF6A72E1011  xor         rax,rsp  
00007FF6A72E1014  mov         qword ptr [rsp+38h],rax  
00007FF6A72E1019  movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr [__xmm@000000280000001e000000140000000a (07FF6A72E32C0h)]  
00007FF6A72E1021  lea         rbx,[numbers]  
00007FF6A72E1026  movdqu      xmmword ptr [numbers],xmm0  
00007FF6A72E102C  mov         dword ptr [rsp+30h],32h  
00007FF6A72E1034  mov         edi,5  
00007FF6A72E1039  nop         dword ptr [rax]  
00007FF6A72E1040  mov         edx,dword ptr [rbx]  
00007FF6A72E1042  mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (07FF6A72E3080h)]  
00007FF6A72E1049  call        qword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (07FF6A72E3088h)]  
00007FF6A72E104F  mov         rcx,rax  
00007FF6A72E1052  mov         dl,20h  
00007FF6A72E1054  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (07FF6A72E1110h)  
00007FF6A72E1059  lea         rbx,[rbx+4]  
00007FF6A72E105D  sub         rdi,1  
00007FF6A72E1061  jne         main+40h (07FF6A72E1040h)  
00007FF6A72E1063  mov         rcx,qword ptr [__imp_std::cout (07FF6A72E3080h)]  
00007FF6A72E106A  mov         dl,0Ah  
00007FF6A72E106C  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (07FF6A72E1110h)  
00007FF6A72E1071  xor         eax,eax  
}
```

they are identical.

Comment: _it assumes all iterators are iterators to contiguous array in memory._ - how does the question assume that please?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - it's because the question asks about performance relative to using a pointer. With a plain pointer, the data has to be contiguous.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - sigh. Plain pointers and increment imply arrays. Please don't pull this further down this rathole.

Comment: @PeteBecker The question asks about the price of wrapping a pointer into iterator vs manipulating the pointer directly. Whether it uses increment or chases a list is irrelevant in this context.

Answer (score 4):

If the iterator functions can be inlined then the run-time cost of the abstraction is 0.

This is what Stroustrup calls *zero-overhead abstractions* in [Foundations of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/ETAPS-corrected-draft.pdf):

> In general, C++ implementations obey the
>   zero-overhead principle: What you don’t use, you don’t pay for. And further: What you do use, you couldn’t hand code any better.
>
> Zero-overhead abstraction mechanisms. By “light-weight abstraction,” I mean abstractions that do not impose space or time overheads in excess
>   of what would be imposed by careful hand coding of a particular example of the abstraction.

Benchmark to get hard numbers though.